# Question about removal-notice if sued or compromised

Tags: terminology

What do you call the old notices that say:

> If this notice is removed the site is to be assumed compromised or litigation to compromise the site has been filed.

I used to see these a lot as a social tactic to notify others, but haven't seen them in awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called "warrant canary".